# X-ray. How to parse non-nested structure into array of objects?

Tags: javascript, typescript, web-scraping, x-ray

I'm trying to collect data with x-ray from a page that structured like:

```html
<h1>Page title</h1>
<article>
  <h2 id="first">Title 1</h2>
  <h3>Subtitle 1</h3>
  <ul>
    <li>Element 1
    <li>Element 2
    <li>Element 3
  </ul>
  <h2 id="second">Title 2</h2>
  <h3>Subtitle 2</h3>
  <h2 id="third">Title 3</h2>
  <h3>Subtitle 3</h3>
  <ul>
    <li>Element 1
    <li>Element 2
    <li>Element 3
  </ul>
</article>
```

The article is split in sections with `<h2>`. The section contains subtitle and **may** contain a list of items. My goal is to get an object with the structure:

```
type Result = { 
  pageTitle: string,
  sections: [{ subtitle?: string, elements?: string[] }],
}
```

From that example structure I expect output:

```json
{
  pageTitle: "Page title",
  sections: [
    {
      subtitle: "Subtitle 1",
      elements: ["Element1", "Element2", "Element3"]
    },
    {
      subtitle: "Subtitle 2",   
      elements: [] //or any falsy value
    },
    {
      subtitle: "Subtitle 3",
      elements: ["Element1", "Element2", "Element3"]
    }
  ]
}
```

I've tried:

```
xray(url, {
  pageTitle: "h1 | trim", //where trim is defined filter
  sections: xray("article", [{
    subtitle: "h3",
    elements: ['h3 ~ ul li']
  }])
})
```

But I've figured out that it doesn't work as expected because there is only one `article` tag on the page and `[]` indicates that xray will iterate over whatever selector (`article` in my case) returns

I've also tried:

```
xray(url, {
  pageTitle: "h1 | trim", //where trim is defined filter
  sections: xray("h2", [{
    subtitle: "h3",
    elements: ['h3 ~ ul li']
  }])
})
```

This returns 0 results, probably because `xray("h2", /* other code */)` "scopes" selection to only h2 and nothing else. And my h2's doesn't contain nested elements.

So is there a way to get array of objects from a non-nested html structure?

Comment: Can you create a reproducible snippet or fiddle?

Comment: Does a Python solution work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

X-ray library doesn't provide an easy way to capture sibling elements within its syntax. It primarily works with a parent-child relationship and the structure you're trying to scrape doesn't conform to that pattern.

Ideally library like Puppeteer would be more suitable, but x-ray with jsdom can handle it too.

The solution is to pre-process the HTML to encapsulate each section within a separate container, then scrape that new structure with x-ray.

**Steps:**

1. Load the HTML into a jsdom
2. Iterate over each  element, collect  and  siblings until the next
3. Wrap each group in a new
4. Pass the HTML to x-ray

**Code:**

```
    const { JSDOM } = require("jsdom");
    const xray = require("x-ray")();
    
    const html = /* Your HTML here */;
    
    const dom = new JSDOM(html);
    const document = dom.window.document;
    
    let currentDiv;
    document.querySelectorAll("h2").forEach((h2, index) => {
      if (index === 0) {
        currentDiv = document.createElement("div");
        h2.parentNode.insertBefore(currentDiv, h2);
      } else {
        currentDiv = document.createElement("div");
        currentDiv.appendChild(document.createElement("br")); // Separator
        h2.parentNode.insertBefore(currentDiv, h2);
      }
    
      let sibling = h2;
      do {
        currentDiv.appendChild(sibling);
        sibling = sibling.nextElementSibling;
      } while (sibling && sibling.tagName !== "H2");
    });
    
    const processedHtml = document.body.innerHTML;
    
    xray(processedHtml, {
      pageTitle: "h1 | trim",
      sections: xray("div", [{
        subtitle: "h3",
        elements: ["ul li"]
      }])
    })((err, result) => {
      console.log(result);
    });
```

It makes extensive use of DOM manipulation which may not be ideal

Answer (score 0):

**Potential Approach** - i would also suggest some more code to help with the approach

```
xray(url, {
  pageTitle: "h1 | trim",
  sections: xray("h2", [{
    subtitle: "+ h3",
    elements: ['+ h3 + ul li']
  }])
});
```

Comment: It almost work, but not quite. with this approach `elements` always empty
`{"pageTitle":"Page title","sections":[{"elements":[]},{"elements":[]},{"elements":[]}]}`. Tested on the example from question